# ng-tags-input autocomplete is not displayed

Tags: json, angularjs, autocomplete, ng-tags-input

I try to use ng-tags-input with a returned Json list by an api controller .net Mvc 6. My list is created in json but when try to display this list with the autocompletion , nothing works. My autocomplete list isn't displayed and I don't have error in chrome console.

So this is an object of my list :

```
[{
  "ShopID":1,
  "CompanyID":1,
  "RegionID":1,
  "Name":"Les Pieux",
  "Town":"Les Pieux",
  "Address":null,
  "ZipCode":null,
  "CreateDate":"2006-01-01T00:00:00",
  "ModificationDate":"2006-09-29T00:00:00",
  "LastModificationUserID":1,
  "PhoneNumber":null,
  "Fax":null,
  "Email":null,
  "CEmployeeShop":null
 }]
```

This is my method in my controller:

```
 $scope.tokenShops = [];
 $scope.loadJsonShops = function(query)
    {
        //$scope.shops contains my list of shops in json format.
        return $scope.shops;
    }
```

And the tag in Html:

```
<div ng-controller="EmployeesCtrl">
            <tags-input ng-model="tokenShops"
                        display-property="Name"
                        Placeholder="Ajouter un magasin"
                        add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
                <auto-complete resource="loadJsonShops($query)"></auto-complete>
            </tags-input>
        </div>
```

This is my code that populates $scope.shops

Api Controller:

```
public IEnumerable<Shop> Get()
{
    using (LSContext db = new LSContext())
    {
        var listShop = db.Shops.ToList();
        return listShop;
    }
}
```

angular shopCtrl:

```
function ShopsCtrl($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
function getShopsList() {
    var reqGetShops = $http({ url: 'api/Shops' });
    reqGetShops.success(function (data) {
        $scope.shops = data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast("getListShops", { list: data });
    });
}
//with api controller the list is returned in json format. I tried an another method to fill my list with an convertion that I do and it doesn't work.
```

angularjs EmployeeCtrl :

```
$scope.$on("getListShops", function (event, args) {
    $scope.shops = args.list;
    $scope.selectShop = args.list[0];
})
```

But I don't think that my problem from my json list.
I hope someone can help me . Have a nice day.

Comment: Where's the code that populates $scope.shops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve my problem with a directive:

```
angular.module('TagsDirective', ['myResources', 'resourcesManagerGet', 'translateI18n'])
.directive('tags', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',//restraint pour les éléments du dom
        template: '<tags-input ng-model="SShops" key-property="ShopID" display-property="Name" placeholder="{{\'AddShop\' | i18n}}" add-from-autocomplete-only="true"><auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete></tags-input>',
        scope: false,

        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.loadTags = function (query) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var reqGetShops = $http({ url: 'api/Shops/GetListShopFiltered', params: { 'query': query } });
                reqGetShops.success(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and in Html:

```
<tags></tags>
```

g0loob :  thanks for your help, but now you can put an array of objects and use the attribute display-property to choose the text property to display.

example:http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos and look the tags input with custom object.

Answer (score 0):

`auto-complete` requires array of objects with at least one property named "text" (just like `tags-input`), if you are not using your template for `auto-complete` or `tags-input`. And you also need to filter your result for `auto-complete` in order to work properly. Also see this [link](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos).

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('TagsDirective', ['myResources', 'resourcesManagerGet', 'translateI18n'])
.directive('tags', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',//restraint pour les éléments du dom
        template: '<tags-input ng-model="SShops" key-property="ShopID" display-property="Name" placeholder="{{\'AddShop\' | i18n}}" add-from-autocomplete-only="true"><auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete></tags-input>',
        scope: false,

        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.loadTags = function (query) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var reqGetShops = $http({ url: 'api/Shops/GetListShopFiltered', params: { 'query': query } });
                reqGetShops.success(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
```